# Unity "OnEditorRefresh"?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm creating a utility library to simplify **GameObject**s management. The problem is that when I store **GameObject**s in a script, after editing sources and going back to *Unity*'s window, every **GameObject** is cleared from the different scripts, so I have to update them all.

For the moment, I'm checking if a **GameObject** exists in the script in the  `Update()` function, and gather it back when missing. But that is a bit heavy for nothing.

The best would be a `OnEditorRefresh()` function to override, which is called each time *Unity* refresh its cached **GameObject** references (after the little freeze when it updates from the recently modified scripts). Would anything like that exist ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the **[InitializeOnLoad](http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/RunningEditorCodeOnLaunch.html)** attribute with a static constructor. This will be called upon every time the scripts recompile.

Comment: Excellent ! That works perfectly. I would add that as it uses `using UnityEditor`, you need to put `#if UNITY_EDITOR ... #endif` in order to compile without error.

Comment: You can avoid that by placing that particular script in a an 'Editor/' folder, this way, it won't be comiled during build time. See http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/SpecialFolders.html for more information.

Comment: Even better ! Thanks ! :) Except if the class is used even in the compiled version, but doesn't need to perform anything with the Editor once compiled. Then the `#if` here would do the job.